# how to use indexpath for xml parsing

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsxmlparser, nsindexpath

i am passing data from one view to the other using xml parser.when i click on any row(after the xml is loaded on the view) it should display the entire details accordingly.
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UILabel *titleLabel = nil;
    UILabel *priceLabel = nil;

    UILabel *titleValueLabel = nil;
    UILabel *priceValueLabel = nil;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)];
        titleLabel.text = @"Model:";

        priceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 50, 20)];
        priceLabel.text = @"Price:";


        priceValueLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 20, 50, 20)];
        titleValueLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 1, 320, 20)];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:priceLabel];


        [cell.contentView addSubview:titleValueLabel];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:priceValueLabel];

    }


    NSDictionary *tempProduct = [self.listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDictionary *productTitle = [tempProduct valueForKey:TITLE];
    NSString *titleValue = [productTitle valueForKey:TEXT];
    titleValue = [titleValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
              [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    titleValueLabel.text = titleValue;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:titleValueLabel];


    NSDictionary *productPrice = [tempProduct valueForKey:PRICE];
    NSString *priceValue = [productPrice valueForKey:TEXT];
    priceValue = [priceValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
              [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    priceValueLabel.text = priceValue;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:priceValueLabel];


    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

and my sample xml data is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scan>
    <products>
        <title>samsung galaxy</title>
        <desc>smart phone</desc>
        <price>250$</price>
    </products>
    <products>
        <title>samsung galaxy1</title>
        <desc>smart phone1</desc>
        <price>251$</price>
     </products>
    <products>
        <title>samsung galaxy2</title>
        <desc>smart phone2</desc>
        <price>252$</price>
    </products>
    <products>
        <title>samsung galaxy3</title>
        <desc>smart phone3</desc>
        <price>350$</price>
    </products>
    </scan>
```

when i click on the first row,it should display the same data.but it is displaying in the order of the selection.
how to fix this?

Comment: you have array of object's ...?

Comment: no. i dont have. @nitin gohel

Comment: please read my answer i just change code of your question and put as a my answer you just copy and past in cellforrowAtindexpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just passing index like that

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        NSDictionary *tempProduct = [self.listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)];
       [Name setText:[tempProduct valueForKey:@"TITLE"]];

        priceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 50, 20)];
        [Name setText:[tempProduct valueForKey:@"Price"]];


        priceValueLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 20, 50, 20)];
        titleValueLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 1, 320, 20)];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:priceLabel];


        //[cell.contentView addSubview:titleValueLabel];
       // [cell.contentView addSubview:priceValueLabel];

    }



    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


            NSDictionary *tempProduct = [self.listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

          objAppDelegate.strCatagoryTitle=[tempProduct valueForKey:@"TITLE"];
          objAppDelegate.strCatagoryPrice=[tempProduct valueForKey:@"Price"];

//hear  objAppDelegate.strCatagoryTitle or objAppDelegate.strCatagoryPrice globle string.
//we can use it at our cntrSecondViewController class using this Delegate object 
//objAppDelegate = (cntrAppDelegate1 *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


 cntrSecondViewController *cntrinnerService = [[cntrSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"cntrSecondViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:cntrinnerService animated:YES];


}
```

Comment: the above code worked.thanks :) but after the first click,its not going anywhere.when i click for the second time,its going to the option that has to be displayed after the first click.

Comment: please check you Didselected delegate method

Comment: the code above is working but the first row that is selected is not doing anything unless any other row is selected.it is displaying the previous row's data.how to fix this?@ nitin Gohel

Comment: are you pushing a view or what at selecting particular row..?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19882/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-vinny)

Comment: yes.on selecting a particular row,it navigates to another view that displays the complete details.@nitin Gohe